# Insert values of a form to database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sorry for My Ignorace but codeigniter is new for me. SO I dont know how to insert values to database. So my basic question is I want to understand that how values are inserted from views to controller to model in a database.

This is my controller file...

```
                <?php

                class Form extends CI_Controller {

                        public function index()
                        {
                                $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

                                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                                $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
                                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required',
                                        array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.')
                                );
                                $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
                                $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');


                        }
                }?>
```

This is My View File.

```
                    <?php

                    //print_r($data);

                    echo form_open();
                    ?>
                    <h5>Username</h5>
                    <input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

                    <h5>Password</h5>
                    <input type="text" name="password" value="" size="50" />

                    <h5>Password Confirm</h5>
                    <input type="text" name="passconf" value="" size="50" />

                    <h5>Email Address</h5>
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="" size="50" />

                    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

                    </form>
```

This is model file..

```
                <?php

                class formsubmit extends CI_Model
                {




                }


                ?>
```

sorry With Answer if you can explain me the concept also..on how the input is moving to controller and then database.

Comment: Codeigniter manuals did not help you?

Comment: Controller name cannot by `Form`. Change the name and try.

Comment: no codeigniter manuals are not helping me yet...and at least how should I create function in controller to insert the file into database

Comment: Model User Guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look, a few points...don't name your controller Form...that's a bad idea...and all of this is pretty much straight from the documentation. I'm not reposting your viewcode... This is VERY basic code I'm posting here, and there are better ways of doing things, and probably some more things you are going to want to process in your controller before moving on, but this should at least get you started. Also, don't name your models and controllers things like "form" and "formsubmit" ...it's just not good practice...name them things like "User" and "Users."

Also, don't forget to adjust your routes file accordingly.

This is your controller

```
<?php

class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
            {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required',
                                            array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.')
                                    );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('index_view', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->model('Users_model');
            $this->Users_model->insert_user();
            $this->load->view('your_success_view');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This is your model:

```
<?php

class Users_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function insert_user()
    {    
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email')
        );

        // users is the name of the db table you are inserting in
        return $this->db->insert('users', $data);
    }   
}
?>
```