# how can i save input value from foreach loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

`$all_student_record_info`

has student details like student name father name roll no. and section etc. last input field  `<td><input type="text" name="score[]"></td>`

for input each student's score. how can I save score for each student in MySQL. I really don't have any clue how do I write code to save from foreach loop.

```
<?php if (!empty($all_student_record_info)): foreach ($all_student_record_info as $v_student_record) : ?>

       <tr>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="student_id[]"  value="<?php echo $v_student_record->student_id ?>"> <?php echo $v_student_record->student_id ; ?></td>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="school_id[]"  value="<?php echo $v_student_record->school_id ?>"> <?php echo $v_student_record->school_name ?></td>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="class_id[]"  value="<?php echo $v_student_record->class_id ?>"> <?php echo $v_student_record->classes_name ?></td>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="section_id[]"  value="<?php echo $v_student_record->section_id ?>"> <?php echo $v_student_record->section_name ?></td>                                
       <td><?php echo $v_student_record->student_name ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $v_student_record->student_father_name ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $v_student_record->student_contact_number ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $v_student_record->student_address ?></td>                                
       <td><input type="text" name="score[]"></td>                              
       </tr>
<?php
endforeach;
        ?>
<?php else : ?>
      <td colspan="3">
      <strong>There is no data to display</strong>
      </td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

any help please.
 MySQL table would be like this

```
score_id | student_id | school_id | class_id | section_id | score
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert values of a form to database in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383371/insert-values-of-a-form-to-database-in-codeigniter)

Comment: no, that's a simple form. I know how to save that. I am talking about input field within foreach loop

Comment: @LEARNER you want to update or insert ?

Comment: I want to insert

Answer (score -1):

if i understand you correctly - the problem you have to group your data - otherwise there is no possibility to assign the data properly

imho you can try this

```
<?php 
if (!empty($all_student_record_info)): 
    foreach ($all_student_record_info as $v_student_record) : 
?>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="score[<?=$v_student_record->score_id; ?>][student_id]"  value="<?php echo $v_student_record->student_id ?>"> <?php echo $v_student_record->student_id ; ?></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="score[<?=$v_student_record->score_id; ?>][school_id]"  value="<?php echo $v_student_record->school_id ?>"> <?php echo $v_student_record->school_name ?></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="score[<?=$v_student_record->score_id; ?>][class_id]"  value="<?php echo $v_student_record->class_id ?>"> <?php echo $v_student_record->classes_name ?></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="score[<?=$v_student_record->score_id; ?>][section_id]"  value="<?php echo $v_student_record->section_id ?>"> <?php echo $v_student_record->section_name ?></td>                                
    <td><?php echo $v_student_record->student_name ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $v_student_record->student_father_name ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $v_student_record->student_contact_number ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $v_student_record->student_address ?></td>                                
    <td><input type="text" name="score[<?=$v_student_record->score_id; ?>][score]"></td>                              
 </tr>
<?php
    endforeach;
else : 
?>
      <td colspan="3">
      <strong>There is no data to display</strong>
      </td>
<?php 
endif; 
?>
```

Now, if you look @your post array you'll see your data are grouped by score_id (i assumed this is the desired field - because you listed it as the first item in your mysql example)

Comment: and how I write in controller to save in mysql

Comment: bytheway `$all_student_record_info` fetch data from different table and there are no column  `score_id` . I am fetching student name class etc from studentrecord table and saving score with student id into `student_score` table that has `score_id` column with `auto_increment`

Comment: no offense men i gave you a possibility how to solve such problems, if you've tried something which doesn't work out - i'm certainly willing to help, but i'm not gonna write an entire controller code for you