# How to put check box value to database by Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, checkbox

I have a problem with checkbox in codeigniter,i am not able to understand how to implement the code. please help me to implement .

My code will be ,Suppose I have 3 check box(like : Item 1 ,Item 2,Item 3) and  when I will checked the check box then 1 will insert to Database other wise 0 will insert . Please describe me in details.

This is my code

```html
<form>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox disabled">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="" disabled>Option 3</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please show your code?

Comment: Can you try adding some code of what have you tried doing so far. If I understood , you want on a check to update record in DB. This would require you to set JS listener for change on all checkbox's and send Ajax request to update in DB. Otherwise if you want you could set HTML form and checkbox elements as name='someData[]' this will pass you array of data to backend and you can update them .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert values of a form to database in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383371/insert-values-of-a-form-to-database-in-codeigniter)

Comment: I added my code like this .

Answer (score 2):

Check boxes are rather funny things. They only actually post something if their value is 1. Knowing this, we have to handle them a bit differently:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="somename" value="">Option 1</label>
</div>
```

Somewhere in controller:

```
$checkbox = ($this->input->post('somename') == 1 ? '1' : '0');
```

Value will be 1 if checked, 0 otherwise. Input's post function returns null if there is no post data e.g. if the checkbox isn't checked and hence 1.

*Note: don't forget to name your inputs!*